# Is there any scripting language available which is exactly similar to expect script of linux

Tags: windows, scripting, expect

I want to use the linux expect scripts in windows. I tried with perl expect module `expect.pm` in windows, its not working.

Please suggest me is there any language is available in windows that is similar to expect, without using cygwin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) is a free software above Tcl, so I suppose you should have Tcl installed on your system. And according to its web page, *expect* has been ported to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

[ActiveState](http://activestate.com) provides [Expect for Windows](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/expect)

Answer (score 1):

Basile is correct, Expect has been ported to Windows. If you install ActiveState's version of Tcl, you will then have to install Expect separately as it does not come bundled with it (anymore). Once you install it, just open up an command prompt and run the following:

teacup install Expect

The ActiveTcl manual that gets installed has great documentation on how to use it (but looks like you already know how to) :)